# System rating for questions.

Tags: discussion

I've been reading some posts about the points award system and it seems there is some controversy on the downvoting rules.

It is well known that in some other web pages one can vote answers with stars, from $\color\red{0}$ being a poor answer, to $5$ being an excellent one.

Would this be remotely possible here at SE? Maybe this would reflect much better what the answer is worth. Note that if there is an answer that is upvoted threefold and downvoted twice, it will have $+1$ as a net result ([example](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/137765/how-to-calculate-int-fracdx3x22/137770#137770)), whilst if it is awarded say $3$, $3$, $4$, but then $1$, $1$, the net average will yield $2$ and a half stars, which would show the answer is under the average (which is usually $3$ - "good").

Maybe this can be put as a side score with upvotes and downvotes.

The idea is not really thought out deeply, so feel free to suggest corrections and critique. If you don't like the proposal feel free to downvote, but let me know why is it you don't like it.

Comment: This meta.SO questions is, to some extent, related: [Feature idea:
Increase granularity of
voting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43349/feature-idea-increase-granularity-of-voting).
(Although the suggestion how to change the voting process in that
question is different.)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Disagree.

Voting is already subjective. This makes it even more subjective, with no real benefit (IMO).

If enough people vote, the up/down voting should lead to similar results.

Then there are the issues of what to do with questions/answers already voted upon, etc.

Answer (score 7):

That amazon.com makes 1, rather than 0, the smallest possible number of stars is imbecilic.  I hope no one will imitate them in that.